# What is this white board called?

Tags: identification, breadboard, hardware

I am just trying to to figure out what this is called.

[image: Electronic Components]

What I am referring to in this picture is the white board with all of the connectors and the led light attached. I am trying to purchase one but I have no idea what they are called.

Comment: Mini 170 Tie Point Solderless Breadboard prototype

Comment: But don't get a mini until you've figured out how to use the ones with rails properly first.

Comment: It is called "missing [current limiting resistor](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49548/led-current-limiting-resistor-and-ohms-law)". It kills your Arduino if you keep doing it that way.

Comment: @jippie: Maybe its one of those 5mm LEDs with internal resistor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is a [Breadboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadboard). It's hooked up to an [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/).

Comment: I added some links; hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know how to add links using my phone... I'm using the app

Answer (score 9):

search for a "breadboard" or "solderless breadboard" and you should be able to find it.